# How to extract last name while avoiding roman numerals

Tags: python, pandas, extract

How to extract only last name (including hyphenated double last names) without roman numerals or other spaces or character?

String in Pandas dataframe representing person's full name can take the following forms:

```
Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Doe II
Jon Doe, IV
Jon A. Doe, V
Jon A. Doe X
Jon Anderson Doe, VI
Jon Anderson Doe VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton, VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton
```

Is regex a good solution? I'm obviously a novice, but would like an efficient solution.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this to remove the roman numerals and comma:

```
import re

x = """Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Doe II
Jon Doe, IV
Jon A. Doe, V
Jon A. Doe X
Jon Anderson Doe, VI
Jon Anderson Doe VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton, VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton""".split('\n')


for s in x:
  print(re.sub(r"(,.)?(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))$", "", s))
```

[out]:

```
Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Doe 
Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon A. Doe 
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Anderson Doe 
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton 
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton
```

Regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/xeZpBD/1

#### Why do you need a complex regex for the roman numerals?

See https://regexr.com/3a406, cos not all `IVXLCDM` are valid roman numerals.

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/validating-roman-numerals-using-regular-expression/
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch06s09.html

#### But how do we remove the last name?

Depends on how it's defined. If it's just the last token from the names, then you can just do this:

```
for s in x:
  print(re.sub(r"(,.)?(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))$", "", s).strip().split(' ')[-1])
```

[out]:

```
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe
Doe-Stapleton
Doe-Stapleton
Doe-Stapleton
```

#### What if last name isn't a single token/word?

E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name

> The rugby player **Rohan Janse van Rensburg**'s surname is **Janse van Rensburg**, not only van Rensburg (which is itself an existing surname).

or

> Andrew **Lloyd Webber**, Baron Lloyd-Webber Kt (born 22 March 1948), is an English composer and impresario of musical theatre.

Shrugs, you need something more than regex for this, maybe a last name list?

Comment: You are a magician, a master, a maestro. This works perfectly and gave me additional valuable insight. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know that this is *entirely* accurate either. For ex. with a last name like `VIX` (not an actual r. numeral) , it returns `V` instead of the whole `VIX` - which I might expect, though could also be wrong. Also, it **doesn't** handle the edge cases OOTB either, such as `Andrew Lloyd Webber`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. How does it not cover Andrew Lloyd Webber? Do you have a revision to this code that would improve it? I see now you posted below. Does your code fix these?

Comment: @Rycliff I was able to do a quick test, for that name it actually seems to return "Webber" as last name - though it's been a while, something might have changed. And nope, my code does not (attempt to) resolve this edge case either, but to be fair I never stated as such.

Answer (score 1):

An *optimized* approach with the `re` module:

```py
import re

strings = """
Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Doe II
Jon Doe, IV
Jon A. Doe, V
Jon A. Doe X
Jon Anderson Doe, VI
Jon Anderson Doe VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton, VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton
"""

_ROMAN_NUMERAL_RE = re.compile(r'^[IVXLCDM]+$')

for name in strings.strip().splitlines():
    words = name.rsplit(' ', maxsplit=2)
    last_name = words[-2].rstrip(',') if _ROMAN_NUMERAL_RE.match(last := words[-1]) else last
    print(f'{name.ljust(35)} - [ {last_name} ]')
```

Result:

```
Jon Doe                             - [ Doe ]
Jon A. Doe                          - [ Doe ]
Jon Anderson Doe                    - [ Doe ]
Jon Doe II                          - [ Doe ]
Jon Doe, IV                         - [ Doe ]
Jon A. Doe, V                       - [ Doe ]
Jon A. Doe X                        - [ Doe ]
Jon Anderson Doe, VI                - [ Doe ]
Jon Anderson Doe VII                - [ Doe ]
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton VII      - [ Doe-Stapleton ]
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton, VII     - [ Doe-Stapleton ]
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton          - [ Doe-Stapleton ]
```

### Performance

This version is actually *much faster* (more than **5x**) than [a more complex approach with `re`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75746786/10237506).

See benchmark tests with `timeit` below:

```py
import re
from timeit import timeit

strings = """
Jon Doe
Jon A. Doe
Jon Anderson Doe
Jon Doe II
Jon Doe, IV
Jon A. Doe, V
Jon A. Doe X
Jon Anderson Doe, VI
Jon Anderson Doe VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton, VII
Jon Anderson Doe-Stapleton
"""

_ROMAN_NUMERAL_RE = re.compile(r'^[IVXLCDM]+$')


def last_name(name: str):
    words = name.rsplit(' ', maxsplit=2)
    return words[-2].rstrip(',') if _ROMAN_NUMERAL_RE.match(last := words[-1]) else last


def last_name_re(name: str):
    return re.sub(r"(,.)?(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))$", "", name).strip().split(' ')[-1]


# for name in strings.strip().splitlines():
#     print(f'{name.ljust(35)} - [ {last_name_re(name)} ]')

n = 100_000

print('re:            ', timeit("""
for name in strings.strip().splitlines():
    last_name(name)
""", globals=globals(), number=n))

print('re (complex):  ', timeit("""
for name in strings.strip().splitlines():
    last_name_re(name)
""", globals=globals(), number=n))
```

Results on my Mac:

```
re:             0.42575412476435304
re (complex):   3.725017166696489
```